# unable to validate the form and show the error message

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to validate the input field using bootstrap and angularjs.
In the below sample html code i'm trying to validate the input field and display the error on the balloon(Enter the Valid input..) if the input field is not valid or is empty, but it is not working with the code.

Please find the demo : http://next.plnkr.co/edit/WoQC2jugwxpG2bc9

Sample code:

```
<div>
     Single/Multiple email:
    <input type="email" class="form-control" multiple-emails required 
           name="recipientEmail" ng-model="recipientEmail">
    <div ng-show="shareSelectionForm.$submitted || shareSelectionForm.recipientEmail.$touched">
        <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="headerForm.recipientEmail.$error.required">
          Enter the Valid input..
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="submitForm()">
  Submit
</button>
```

Any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check if form is submitted using shareSelectionForm.$submitted.

In submitForm() fuction,

add $scope.submitted = true;

And use this variable in your html to check if the form has been submitted

```
<div>
     Single/Multiple email:
    <input type="email" class="form-control" multiple-emails required 
           name="recipientEmail" ng-model="recipientEmail">
    <div ng-show="submitted || shareSelectionForm.recipientEmail.$touched">
        <p class="error-mesg" ng-show="shareSelectionForm.recipientEmail.$error.required">
          Enter the Valid input..
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="submitForm()">
  Submit
</button>
```

In paragraph's ng-show you had used a different form name - headerForm.
Form name is shareSelectionForm.